# Delete TextBox with Button in separate Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, class, textbox

I would like delete the value from TextBox 'txtName' by using a separate class 'Delete', with the methode .resetText().
i don't get access in this separate class to my TextBox.
how can i solve this problem?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void butDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete delete = new Delete();
    }
}


class Delete
{
    public Delete()
    {
        txtName.ResetText();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass text box object as paramter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass text box object as parameter.

```
class Delete
{
    public Delete(TextBox txtName)
    {
        txtName.ResetText();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `ref TextBox txtName`?

Comment: @Auditive is it required ? I don't think so.

Comment: @Auditive `ref` used here would mean that you could create a new instance of a TextBox **within** `Delete` and completely replace the passed in TextBox with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Send your textbox cotrol with parametr of your Delete method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void butDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete delete = new Delete();
        delete.Delete(txtName);
    }
}


class Delete
{
    public Delete(Control control)
    {
         var txtBox = control as TextBox;
         if (txtBox == null)
            return;
         txtBox.ResetText();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need this: `var txtBox = control as TextBox;`: `ResetText()` belongs to the `Control` class. It would be different if you used the `Clear()` method, which belongs to the TextBoxBase class. But, in this case, you would add a different constraint, `public Delete(TextBoxBase control)`. The null check is also not necessary, just write `control?.ResetText();`

Comment: Control and TextBoxBase are referance types, i think it doesn't matter much. TextBoxBase class also inherits from Control )

Comment: This has nothing to do with Reference Types, but with inheritance. There's no point in defining the parameter as `Control control` and then cast to TextBox if you need to use a method that belongs to the Control class. Just define the parameter as `TextBox` or don't cast. If you want to add a constraint to the TextBox class, add it to the parameter. Otherwise, it's not clear why passing a Button as argument does nothing.

Comment: i think this is correct! my method is more extensible, for example, if further,  wants to make a reset for RichTextBox or for ComboBox, etc.

Comment: If you want to make it more generic, as mentioned and described, the method is just: `public Delete(Control control) { control?.ResetText(); }`. Now you ca pass any Control.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void butDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete delete = new Delete(txtName);
    }
}


class Delete
{
    public Delete(TextBox txtName)
    {
        txtName.ResetText();
    }
}
```